# Make the editor hint users to add code fences when a curly brace in paragraph text leads into a code block

Tags: feature-request, editor

For curly-brace languages, it's not too difficult to find posts that are missing code fences with a high true-positive rate: Just find posts where paragraph text ends with an opening curly brace and leads into a code block (typically, four spaces in the markdown editor, but more if the code block goes with a list entry. You also need to be intentional about catching cases in blockquotes).

These can also be retroactively found via SEDE. [Here's a query that finds recent examples (ones that start from 2023 and onward)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1701033/recent-2023-curly-lang-missing-code-fences):

```sql
SELECT P.Id AS [Post Link], P.Body
FROM Posts P
WHERE
  P.Id >= 74972583 -- optimized version of CreationDate > '2023-01-01'
  AND CHARINDEX('{</p>'+CHAR(10)+'<pre><code>', P.Body COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) <> 0
```

How about having the editor detect this on the fly to give a hint about possibly missing code fences?

Comment: It would be possible to hint this for Python, too, although it would have a high false-negative rate (for code that starts with an assignment) and non-zero false positive rate. Just scan for lines that start with `import`, or which end with a colon while starting with (off the top of my head) any of `if`,`def`, `while`, `for`,`try`,`class`, `with`. Considerably more complex than just looking for `{`, but still a matter of simple string searches - not even regex required, let alone tokenization or parsing.