# Are SE staff testing the AI formatting assistant on real questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, formatting-assistant

I just stumbled across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76506701/2) in which a staff member made some English tweaks. What struck me as odd though, is that they added "thanks", [which is considered noise and is supposed to be *removed* from posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587). Later on, they transcribed the code from the image to text, which isn't in accordance with community consensus [as discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415040/11107541) and [as written in the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/11107541). The staff member has been [editing several posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20511809/cobih?tab=activity&sort=revisions) in the past half hour, all with the same muster, smelling of AI use.

Does that mean that ["as of 2023-06-18 7:42 UTC the question formatting assistant experiment has been turned off"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425162/5211833) actually meant "only for regular users"?

This is a perfect example of why AI editing is far from perfect yet and in certain cases, e.g. adding "thanks" or transcribing images, in direct conflict with the current rules on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76506511/revisions) is also a very questionable edit.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with AI. Over in MSE many staff members who are not CM's add "thanks" and signatures, out of sheer habit of posting online, or emails. They simply have no idea what the site rules or culture are, which is expected. Product manager doesn't have to know the product, just make it sell well.

Comment: Why do you think these are AI posts? Especially the edit transcribing the image content doesn't look AI'ish.

Comment: The AI aspect aside, this is a perfect example of why edits made by people with little experience of how the site works should go through a review queue.

Comment: We do not allow "thanks"?...it's not a bloat or something terrible to say

Comment: @machine_1 It is bloat, as it doesn't add any useful information to the question. What certainly doesn't make sense is for some third party to add such text to OP's post while editing it.

Comment: This also looks like abuse of their staff diamond privilege. Their edits should go through the review queue like every other 1-rep user.

Comment: Yes, it is bloat, @machine_1. Heaps of text have been written regarding the matter, so I'll just point towards the **official** Help Center [page defining expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) on the network: "Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat.".

Comment: @TylerH How can they? Doesn’t the system automatically accept them, thereby preventing them from going to the review queue? It’s not the individual staff member’s fault that the system is this way.

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype My point is that this staff user should probably not have a diamond. They probably don't actually need one to do their job, and it's clear they are misusing it here by making bad edits to questions that circumvent review queues. The edit Adriaan mentioned first also changed a non-opinion-based question into an opinion-based one... literally every aspect of that revision was bad.

Comment: I mean... they could also just take the post source and test it in their dev environment.

Comment: These are the edits that we would usually send a warning about and if it doesn't stop suspend the user. But since moderators are on strike this is unlikely to happen.

Comment: @Dharman, strike aside, is that what you _can_ do to a staff member's account?

Comment: Wait, why is it bad to transcribe the code? My first impression of this policy is that it seems counterintuitive, did I miss a discussion thread somewhere?

Comment: @ahiijny https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Comment: Or more specifically, @ahiijny : [Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040/should-we-edit-a-question-to-transcribe-code-from-an-image-to-text)

Comment: A canonical is *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)* (MSE).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I edited the question post to point to a more general MSE Q&A on noise.

Comment: The first revision smells of AI use to me too. No matter how many times I regenerate the suggestion for the post using the Ask Question AI, the opening line ends up starting with "I have", and it has been known to add "thanks" to posts (but I didn't see that with this post). Transcribing the image is not something that the AQ AI would be able to do, but there's lots of other software that could do it.

Comment: @Laurel: Which one? 76506511 (mentioned in comments)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen "[this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76506701/2)", the first link.

Comment: Staff having no idea what they’re doing, and abusing their editing rights, seem like good reasons to consider signing [the strike letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/).

Comment: FYI, since several people complained about the diamond, staff [don't appear to need a diamond to edit without review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344161/566903)

Comment: It's also noteworthy to me how the current Ask Question Wizard is demonstrably worsening the quality of the questions under discussion. The "seam" where OP stopped answering "What are the details of your problem?" and started answering "What did you try and what were you expecting?" is obvious. Properly written answers may or may not include information addressing both those points (they're overly focused on "my existing code doesn't work" situations, which are not at all the only kind of on-topic question), but should incorporate them naturally instead.

Comment: @pppery from what I can tell, it's more like "staff automatically get a diamond next to their name, and a "mod" tag in contexts that would display it, and all the corresponding privileges, even though they don't necessarily show up on the listing of moderators". At least, this one [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) appear on the list, but [does](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20511809/cobih) get such a tag.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Some, but not all, staff have diamonds and have all the powers of a moderator.  Generally the ones that do need it for reasons related to their job.  The CMs all have diamonds, and I think most (all?) devs do as well.  The ones that don't have diamonds have only the specific abilities listed in [the post that pppery linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344161/165261).

Comment: The real question is why there was 6 edits to a "picture of code" question which should just have been closed. Lipstick on a pig. Or in this case, sloppy spray paint on a pig...

Comment: Being a [staff] member doesn't mean you know how to use the tools. I'm sure that's something many of the users here are reminded of on a frequent basis (and I'm not talking specifically about [so] staff).

Comment: It seems the editor does not yet have the `informed` badge. Maybe someone could tell them about the tour to get familiar with the site :P

Comment: Rather: half-decent manager skills suggest that when hiring someone fresh out of school/no relevant domain experience, you can't just toss them in at the deep end of the basin and walk away. Someone experienced in using the sites should be put in charge of them. _Awful_ managers won't even do that, but fire the experienced staff and replace them with inexperienced ones, again without giving them time to learn, then tell them to spend 8 hours a day chasing some poorly-defined buzzword for poorly-defined purposes.

Comment: We saw lots of such companies and managers around the IT crash year ~2002. They all went rapidly bankrupt. As usual the only thing we can learn from history is that humans never learn from history.

Answer (score 106):

These edits are no doubt concerning, and when I was notified about them, I immediately asked the staff member in question to stop until I had a chance to talk to them (the changes happened on a day that I was not working and would not be able to further investigate) and find out exactly what was happening. They confirmed to me that they would stop making any changes immediately (and they did so), and that they would be happy to talk to me, but they are on vacation this week. We will be following up next week so that I can get the full context about what happened here and determine whether any of the edits were AI-assisted, AI-generated, or none of the above.

At that point, once I understand better what exactly was going on, I will be certain that the staff member will get some follow-up training from one of my community managers on the appropriate ways to contribute, including when it's inappropriate to edit using the diamond and the community norms.

I apologize for the disruption here, and ask for your patience while we determine exactly what the situation is. It is not our practice to make "practice" changes on the live site (we have several different demo environments to work in), and I agree that these do not (on surface) seem to be natural organic changes, but they do seem to be practice/test changes.
I will follow up with the staffer and their manager once they're back from vacation. I would like to request that there not be any further speculation here, until we know what we're actually dealing with.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt attention to this matter, and for your honest, direct response. Very much appreciated (always, and especially now). Please feel free to let the mods know if we can be of any help in offering guidance, suggestions, etc.

Comment: "_We will be following up next week so that I can get the full context about what happened here and determine whether any of the edits were AI-assisted, AI-generated, or none of the above._" Why not ask someone else who knew about what they were doing and why? Or do you mean to imply that there's _on one else_ in the company who knew they were doing this?

Comment: @starball The staff member has made some independent edits that seem to have been for practicing purposes. Management cannot always be aware of everything their employees do. And a vacation is a valid reason to delay talking about an instance. While yes, the edits were bad, and stirred up the community, they haven’t done much real irrevocable harm, or require any immediate action from the employee. It’s quite clearly a single person’s action. No other staff members have made similar edits, and these edits are few, so there’s not much reason to doubt Philippe’s words in this case.

Comment: I see no reason to speculate any much further in the light of this update, as it’s an adequate description of what’s happened. It seems to have been a single person’s mistake. Further speculation only makes it more personal, and puts much attention at an employee that made an unsupervised mistake, for no real gain. I’d leave the staff member alone, though discussing the company as a whole is still possible. But I don’t see how that’s interesting, as long as this is nothing more than a single person’s minor mistake, which may even have happened off-work for all we know.

Comment: This was a good find by the community, and deserved to be brought up in the light of the recent events, though. If it so is that a new staff member went rogue with a new toy, there’s no reason to put that on a public pillory past this point. Such is best handled internally.

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype yeah I agree. I guess I wasn't clear on my point: If nobody else was aware of this in the organization, I think this is an organizational issue. Where were the guardrails? Where was the training? Where was the internal unity / communication? This is preventable stuff. Notice that I wasn't in any way trying to draw more attention to that particular staff. My comment was about the staff as a team.

Comment: \*(staff (plural) as a team). like- IIRC, there was training provided for the last community-a-thon. we have a Help Center page on editing, a MSO FAQ page on editing, a MSE FAQ page on editing, and similar pages on close-voting, and the non-inline editing page has guidance on editing. The fact that none of that was sufficient here should raise some serious questions about how things can be systematically improved within the company and in the network sites' implementation.

Comment: I'm not saying I'm perfect. I can't begin to count the number of times I've done things wrong too, but that kind of just feeds into the previous point.

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype "Management cannot always be aware of everything their employees do." They did give this individual full moderator rights on the live site however. The management problem: why is an employee who doesn't even understand how the product works is trusted with full moderator access to it. Perhaps it would be sensible to just give them full moderator rights on some test build/repo and not on the live site.

Comment: @Lundin - that's an option that's open to us, and one that we do on a regular basis when the employee doesn't have a need for mod rights on production servers.  We have a number of environments for that. However, certain employees have need (expressed or assumed, depending - Community Management is assumed need, for instance)  to the mod tools.  It's not given automatically, ever. Someone from my team is involved in all of the recent ones (not always true in the past, but true now).  Onboarding and community training is an area that I'm in the midst of revamping right now.

Comment: @Philippe Ok, seems you have tracked down the cause of the problem then. It's curious why SO have so many devs who don't even know how SO works, however. Finding _anyone_ working with web development who does _not_ know how at least the basics of how to use SO is probably quite hard for the average software company. I would think experience of using SO might be a nice merit or even a requirement when hiring devs to work with the site itself.

Comment: The staff member in question is not a developer.

Comment: @starball Yeah, this an example of something that’s gone wrong within the organization, but there’s a level of trust that needs to be within any organization, meaning, others not knowing that this happened, isn’t the issue. The issue is that it could happen in the first place. It’s a symptom of an impaired organization, along with many other signs. Well, the entire AI venture is a symptom of something being seriously wrong.

Comment: @Lundin I don't know why that would be a huge surprise when the disconnect between how curators are trying to keep the site working and what random devs want the site to be is so large.

Comment: @Philippe So you gave someone who isn't a dev and doesn't know the site moderator access. That's an even bigger problem then. I can't see why anyone but devs and CMs need that.

Comment: Product managers need access.  Designers need parts of the tool set, and we don't have  the rights subset.  Engineers.  Community Managers.  Info Sec.... it's quite a long list of potential needs.

Comment: Do we have an update on what happened?

Comment: Fair question.  I was out due to a death in the family, but my understanding from those who dealt with it is that the staff member in question was contacted and connected with a member of my team for some mentoring on site and as someone to ask questions of.  We'll monitor and watch for recurrence, but we're also amping up the on-boarding and training for new employees to try to head off future circumstances that are similar.  I've asked Catija from my team to work with me on that piece of it.

Comment: Thank you for the update. It doesn't, however, answer the crucial part of the question: was the staff member testing/using AI tools to edit those posts?

Comment: Yes, they were.  They are now aware of the error of their ways, and I am assured that it will not be repeated.  And as I said, we're going to monitor and watch for reoccurrence and make changes to our onboarding and training to prevent future incidents.

Comment: Thank you for you honesty and (assuming these changes are actually been made of course) your efforts to prevent this in the future.

Answer (score 78):

Some feedback to the Staff that made those edits:

rev 2 in https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76506506/revisions fixes several oddities such as a weird semicolon where there probably shouldn't be one, changes the name of a file to a more conventional one, and fixes invalid JSON. Changing the semantics of what the question asker writes obscures issues the asker could actually be facing ([I was concerned about this from the start](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425087/11107541)). [The team working on the Formatting Assistant tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425208/11107541), but it's evidently not working.

There's not too much point in trying to polish https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76506504/revisions. It's missing a MRE and has now been closed. See [How to Ask's section on Helping others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [Five days into the release of ChatGPT, I was already suggesting directing efforts instead to deeper issues like posts lacking enough detail, or enough of the right kinds of detail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384378/997587). Feel free to polish stuff that should be closed, but stuff that should be closed should be closed.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76506701/revisions "best" is a pet peeve of mine. Best in terms of... what? This is software. We deal in a world of tradeoffs. The original question post didn't say anything about what it wants to optimize for. In fact- It didn't even make *any mention* of wanting something optimized. A single word subtly but fundamentally changed the meaning of the question and changed it into one that lacked details on what to optimize for. Friendly reminder that as an editor, you're generally not supposed to change the meaning of the post. Sometimes I sidestep that rule, but only when I think it doesn't invalidate any existing answers, and significantly increases the value of the Q&A to the rest of the internet.

Comment: They're just [new to the site](https://xkcd.com/2501/). This kind of thing is exactly why we can @-ping editors in comments: to explain why edits are unhelpful.

Comment: I understand the frustration, but the condescending tone is unnecessary.

Comment: @PasserBy the post wasn't written to be condescending. It's frank and blunt (and it was written to be that way). If it reads as condescending to you, you're welcome to edit it to make what you think are improvements.

Comment: I will perhaps when I can. What I'm referring to is  _"This is basic stuff"_ and the likes, which doesn't quite radiate positivity.

Comment: @PasserBy okay to be honest, you're right. I probably came off as harsh, and in the back of my mind meant to. But it was pressing on me. I've gone and softened the post. Thanks for calling it out. Now I go to sleep.

Comment: Instead of "best", that should probably just be "How do I". But the edits on that question was probably a waste of time since the question wasn't really a good fit for the site, and has now been deleted.